Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.3.1-10880808
after upgrading to the latest version of android studio (2024.2.1) and upgrading gradle and AGP I am facing these error messages when try to run on device but gradle sync success:
Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@68af1da1 of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
   > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@68af1da1 of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration3'.
         > Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.3.1-10880808.
           Searched in the following locations:
             - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom
             - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom
           Required by:
               project :app

my build setups are as follow (all files merged with name on top of each section):
file: libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.7.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.10.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
navigationFragment = "2.6.0"
navigationUi = "2.6.0"

[libraries]
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
navigation-fragment = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment", version.ref = "navigationFragment" }
navigation-ui = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui", version.ref = "navigationUi" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }




file: build.gradle(application)
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
}



file: build.gradle(module :app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 35
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.navigation.fragment
    implementation libs.navigation.ui
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}




file: gradle-wrappers.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


file: settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'




this is a sample project for android studio.
android studio 2024.2.1 running on a ubuntu 20.04
what I've done so far?

removing android studio and all SDKs and gradle files, and installing from zero
changing gradle JDK version to 11, 17, 21
testing all compile sdk versions with AGP and gradle version from this source (developer.android.com)
removing caches and files and redownloading all
rebooting system multiple times
invalidating cache and restarting android studio multiple times
setting multiple new proxies (tested proxies)
even downloaded the given URL in error message manually that existed
creating new projects from android studio wizard multiple times
downloading all files in SDK manager (~20GB)
exploring the stackoverflow and doing all accepted answers (although they are for previous versions)

but the error is not GONE yet and problem persists.
I believe knowing gradle issues is a long journey that I've failed in it.
(the config and error messages don't match because I tested all variations and copy wrong configs)
update:
after adding below lines to build.gradle(project) top level:
buildscript {
repositories{
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    classpath("com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.7.0-12006047")

}
}

the error changed to below:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.


Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@337bd7f9 of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@337bd7f9 of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration2'.
> Failed to transform aapt2-8.7.0-12006047-linux.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.7.0-12006047) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Could not find aapt2-8.7.0-12006047-linux.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.7.0-12006047).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.7.0-12006047/aapt2-8.7.0-12006047-linux.jar

again I can download the link in the above error manually, it's a multi megabytes .jar file
but I don't know why android studio is not able to download it

after days of exploring and investigating the problem I fixed this ugly problem.
I don't know why the heck the gradle was bypassing the proxy for downloading the AGP (android build tools for gradle) and firewall was blocking the connection. (not effected by other files)
I fixed this issue by syncing the project manually using gradlew command line and setting the proxy in args
from bottom left side of android studio (version ladybug) I opened the terminal which is already in projects main directory then entered the below command:
./gradlew assembleDebug -DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=1234

where socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort are variant and up to you.
mine were localhost and 1234 (because I used local socks proxy and bound to port 1234)
and thanks for Erden Savasci and Robert that tried to help me <3

Honestly, when i check the URL "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom", it gives correct response and downloads POM file but could you also please try below setting as defining new Maven repository with custom Google Maven repository?
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}

Normally google() is shortcut for https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/ but it might also worth to try above setting.
Links

https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/8.3.1-10880808/aapt2-8.3.1-10880808.pom

All these URLs seem to be correct.

jcenter() is dead (finally shut down in Aug 2024). Please do not post answers that contain this repository.

thanks for your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work, I tried it with multiple proxies. the file can be downloaded manually with and without attempted proxies but gradle fails.

BTW, can I download it manually and put it somewhere to bypass gradle downloading it?

sorry but I made some changes and error is changed too. I updated the Question.
